# Запятая перед И, придаточная часть или нет?

Tags: запятые, союзы, спп, и, придаточное-предложение

Мне тяжело даются запятые перед И, но со временем правила становятся всё больше понятны. Однако вопрос вызвало вот такое предложение:

***Если обнаружим нарушения, то компенсируем их и не оставим ситуацию без внимания.***

Не нужно ли обособить "то компенсируем их", чтобы обозначить придаточную часть?
Вот так:

***Если обнаружим нарушения, то компенсируем их(,) и не оставим ситуацию без внимания***

Пытаюсь использовать метод вопроса:

- если обнаружим нарушения, то компенсируем их
- если обнаружим нарушения, то не оставим ситуацию без внимания

Посему запятая не нужна. Верно ли моё мышление?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая перед "и" не нужна:

***Если обнаружим нарушения,** то компенсируем их и не оставим ситуацию без внимания.*

Придаточным условия является первое предложение с союзом "если", а в главном предложении – однородные сказуемые "компенсируем" и "не оставим".

Даже если рассматривать часть после "то" как два самостоятельных предложения, то запятую ставить всё равно не нужно, так как у них есть общий элемент – придаточное предложение (см.: [Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133)).

P. S. Вызывает сомнение сочетание "компенсируем их [нарушения]".